# Sweet Alert Pop up Prompt Before Downloading Canvas HTML Image to PNG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, sweetalert

in my Canvas drawing app I have a download to png button, I want to make it so the image off the canvas only downloads when the user clicks "yes save it" on my sweet alert pop up prompt. Right now it's still downloading automatically. Thank you for your help. (also if someone had a better way to download via Javascript that would help too, it's downloading the png but it is corrupt and I can't open it)

```
$('#download').click(function(){
    swal({
        title: "Are you finished your creation?",  
        text: "click yes to save",   
        type: "warning",  
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#f8c1D9",   
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, save it!",  
        closeOnConfirm: true 
    }, function (isConfirm) {      
        if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Saving!");

            var base64 = document.getElementById("canvas")
              .toDataURL("image/png")
              .replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');

            document.getElementById("download-png").href = base64
        } else {

        }

        return false; 
    });
});
```

html

```
<div id="download">
    <a href="#" id="download-png" download="image.png"><img src="./assets/imgs/tools/save.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple: don't use `a[download]` from the start. Create it with javascript and trigger a click event on the node when the user confirms. A simpler alternative is to use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Comment: Ditto @Endless's comment to use FileSaver.JS (or some other saving script) instead of the `download` attribute -- especially since IE does not yet support `download`.

Comment: Thank you @Endless would you know how I could reorganize this if else statement so the pop up prompt requires the user to click yes before it saves, as to the first half of my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include [canvas-toBlob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) into your page and then:

```
function (isConfirm) {      
    if (isConfirm) {
        swal("Saving!");

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

        // get the canvas as a blob
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
            // Save the file...
            saveAs(blob, 'my-image.png')
        }, "image/png", 0.95); // PNG at 95% quality
    } else {
        // user cancel
    }

    return false; 
};
```

Comment: any other suggestions that don't require a plugin? these libraries don't seem to be running properly

Comment: It works perfectly fine to me, just didn't believe i had to write down how to do everything in a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g2s0a2h8/1/

Comment: thank you for your efforts in helping me! :) it turns out it was the order that I had my JS file dependencies in, your solution does work .. much appreciated